# Sending object as json key using angularJs $http in spring controller returns null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, spring

I am trying to send `json` `object`from `javascript` to the `Spring controller`. I am using `angularJs $http post` for that. I am getting the lastName as `null` when I send the `key` as `obejct`. However, when I send the `string` as hard-coded value, the value shows up in the `controller`. Here is the `controller` code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit", method= RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
    public void editInformation(@RequestBody UserDetails userDetails){
        LOGGER.debug("THE LASTNAME IS: "+userDetails.getLastName());
        //codes.....

    }
```

Here is the angularJs code:

```
$fieldProperty =$(this).attr("name");
$inputValue =$(this).val();

$http.post("/app/edit", {$fieldProperty : $inputValue}).success(function(result){
                alert("Success "+result)
            }).error(function(data, status){
                //$log.info("The error is: "+data+ " and the error status code is: "+status)
                alert("failure"+" and the data is: "+data+ " and the stis "+status)
            });
```

Sending `{$fieldProperty : $inputValue}` as JSON returns `userDetails.getLastName()` as null. However, sending `{"lastName" : $inputValue}` returns the proper value. I checked with `alert($fieldProperty)` and it returns `lastName` though.
I am using `Google Gson` library.

Is there something I am missing here. I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To set `$fieldProperty` u have to define the object first. This declaration `({$fieldProperty : $inputValue})` adds the key `'$fieldProperty'` to the Json Obj. Thats why you are getting null for lastName in Spring Controller. U can use this way

```
$fieldProperty =$(this).attr("name");
$inputValue =$(this).val();
var params = {};
params[$fieldProperty] = $inputValue;
$http.post("/app/edit", params).success(function () {
      // Success Callback
});
```